# Insert literal control inside HEAD when <head runat="server"> is not specified?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

I am unable to mark my `<head>` tag `runat="server"` for various reasons.  Is there another way for me to access it and append a literal beneath it?  I need to add a script (as a literal) and have it be the first script referenced under the inside the `<head>` tag.

Maybe using FindControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) server control can be declared without the head element being defined as a server control:

```
<head>
    <asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

Using this you can then add content as required from the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    literal1.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"scripts.js\"></script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `FindControl` to find controls, i.e. elements that are server controls. All other elements are just handled as text in literal controls.

You can put a `PlaceHolder` control in the head tag, then you can add literal controls inside it.